# What are the necessary changes need to create a table in windows azure database?

Tags: azure

I am having the azure database like in the below image.[image: Azure SQL Database]

[image: Managed IP![Database settings][image: Managed IP Settings]

so, what are the changes needs in this or how to create a table in this database?

Answer (score 0):

You can create them by connecting to the database and executing the SQL commands to create your tables (CREATE TABLE reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).

You can do this by using SQL Server Management Studio or by using the Manage button at the bottom command bar in the Azure Management Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

Comment: I can see the "Manage allowed IP addresses" while opening the database am i need to proceed in that?

Comment: And to do this through "SQL server management studio" means, how to do that. Like opening the SQL server management studio and can login the windows azure database from that server?

Comment: Yes, you use SSMS to access your database in Azure and run all the SQL instructions you need. You will need to allow your IP address first, or access will be denied by the firewall.